# Wordpress - Wunderslider fullscreen mode issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm having issues for example in full screen mode that the pictures appear BEHIND the blog - just in front of the background image - instead of in front.

Do you know what could be the issue here?

Many thanks in advance!

http://wunderslider.com/wordpress/fullscreen/

Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you use for the slider "**wunderslider**" makes the div element with class name "wunderslider-wrapper" z-index value -1, making it appear at the back.